# Running multiple RAID-1 arrays on the same server

Tags: motherboard, raid, raid-1

Is it possible to run multiple RAID-1's on the same machine?

I have the following Motherboard: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813182251

Would I need to get RAID cards?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to create multiple RAID-1 arrays on a single computer. Could you add what you already tried and where you ran into problems?

Comment: The manual (http://www.supermicro.com/manuals/motherboard/C202_C204/MNL-1270.pdf) doesn't address the question specifically, but I'd have to say probably. Have you tried setting up more than one RAID-1 set?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  That particular motherboard has a built in RAID controller so you would not have to get a RAID card.  By itself it support 6 SATA 2.0 hard drives and supports RAID 0, 1, 5, and 10.  So you could have up to 3 RAID 1 arrays.